# FileNotFoundException when saving bitmap onto SD card

Tags: java, android, fileoutputstream

I tried to save "viewBitmap" into SD card.

Here is my code:

```
try{
String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
imageFile = new File(mPath, "/snapshot.png");
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
viewBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,outputStream);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
Toast.makeText(Share.this, "Collage was saved.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}catch(Throwable e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

At the line "FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);", an exception was thrown:

[image]

Comment: You didn't even copy-paste your exception into search bar before asking a question.

Comment: you are saving your file into storage which is a secure process in new android apis you have to take runtime permission from code for the such sensitive app functions! thats what error is saying take permission please

Comment: OK I will remember to copy and paste my exception into google first. Thanks

Comment: @Pawel, I think he learned his lesson. Joe Doe, you have to do your homework next time. Here is my upvote for you so you can continue to ask questions. Keep going!

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest.XML file did you add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If the device is running Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher, and the app's targetSdkVersion is 23 or higher, refer to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) to request the permission at run time.